# How do I consume json logs inside Fargate using CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, log4j2, aws-cdk

I have a docker container running in Fargate that emits json logs to the console using [log4j-layout-template](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html).

The logs emitted look like this:

```
{"@timestamp":"2022-03-22T09:08:16.838Z","ecs.version":"1.2.0","log.level":"INFO","message":"Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/8.5.76","process.thread.name":"main","log.logger":"org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-03-22T09:08:16.838Z","ecs.version":"1.2.0","log.level":"INFO","message":"Server built:          Feb 23 2022 17:59:11 UTC","process.thread.name":"main","log.logger":"org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"}
```

I configure my CDK with the following:

```
var def = ingestGatewayTaskDefinition.addContainer(
  id + "Container",
  ContainerDefinitionOptions
    .builder()
    .image(fromEcrRepository(ecrRepository))
    .memoryLimitMiB(memory)
    .cpu(cpu)
    .environment(environment)
    .secrets(secrets)
    .logging(
      LogDriver.awsLogs(
        AwsLogDriverProps
          .builder()
          .logGroup(
            LogGroup.Builder
              .create(this, props.getServiceName())
              .logGroupName("dev/" + props.getServiceName())
              .retention(RetentionDays.ONE_DAY)
              .build()
          )
          .streamPrefix("dev/" + props.getServiceName())
          //.datetimeFormat("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") //??
          .build()
      )
    )
    .build()
);
```

But in Cloud Watch the message portion is the json and is not parsed but [should be discoverable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_AnalyzeLogData-discoverable-fields.html).

How do I parse these fields?

This is what is ends up looking like:
[image: logs]

What I am looking for in Cloud Watch is this:

| @timestamp | ecs.version | log.level | message | log.logger |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-22T09:08:16.838Z | 1.2.0 | INFO | Server version name:... | org.apache... |
| 2022-03-22T09:08:16.838Z | 1.2.0 | INFO | "Server built:... | org.apache... |

Comment: What happens when you expand the message using the arrow button?

Comment: @gshpychka, it picks up the `timestamp` but the `message` looks like formatted json

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question. I assume these fields should be discovered so I can do queries over them.

Comment: Okay, looks like it's parsed correclly, you should be able to query them as is. What is the issue you're running into?

Comment: You are right. If I query `"log.level" = "INFO" ` it filters correctly... I assumed the UI would show the columns...

Comment: Okay, I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the parsing, your events are being parsed correctly.

The following query should work correctly:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter log.level="INFO"
| sort @timestamp desc
```

The Log Stream UI does not show the inferred nested structure, but it's still available for querying.